# Pgfplot Automation tool

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Are there any good graphical software that I can use to draw diagrams/graphs and export them as pgfplot code?

For example, I want to create an histogram so I drag an histogram icon from a menu to the "scene" and tell the program to load the data from what file.. etc.

Comment: Just to get you right: you want a software that you can use with a mouse to configure your plots and that in the end saves you a piece of ``pgfplots`` code with all the parameters used which you can include into your tex file?

Comment: [matlab2tikz](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022) is somewhat useful if you deal with Matlab figures. But other than that I wouldn't know of any "point and click" software able to export to tikz/pgf/pgfplots.

Comment: Benedikt you're right. I already use matlab, but the exported graphs are terrible. But I would like an interface like that with the option to export the resulting graph to pgf.

Comment: @Markus Perhaps you could make that an answer. (And mention [`matplotlib2tikz`](https://github.com/nschloe/matplotlib2tikz) as well, just for reference.)

Answer (score 5):

### Matplotlib

If you use `matplotlib` there are at least two options for generating code that can be included in LaTeX files:

- [The `pgf` backend](http://matplotlib.org/users/pgf.html): recent versions of `matplotlib` has a `pgf` backend, so you can simply do

  ```
  plt.savefig('filename.pgf')
  ```

  to generate a file with `pgf` code.
- [`matplotlib2tikz`](https://github.com/nschloe/matplotlib2tikz): a script written by Nico Schlömer that generates TikZ/`pgfplots` code which can be `\input` in your LaTeX file. See also below.

### Matlab export

[`matlab2tikz`](https://github.com/nschloe/matlab2tikz) (also available on the [MathWorks FileExchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz)), also written by Nico Schlömer, works as `matplotlib2tikz`.

One can specify the width and height of the `pgfplots` plot, and the developer of `matlab2tikz` recommends defining these as macros, so that they can be changed from within the main LaTeX file.

This allows one to quickly create histograms rendered by `pgfplots` with consistent size.

#### Example

```matlab
x = randn(10000,1);
hist(x)
matlab2tikz('testfig.tex')
```

This will generate a file `testfig.tex` in the current folder, that contains a `tikzpicture` with an `axis` environment.

To specify width and height, do for example

```matlab
matlab2tikz('testfig.tex','width','\figw','height','\figh')
```

and have LaTeX code such as

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for dummy text
\newlength\figw
\newlength\figh
\setlength\figw{7cm}
\setlength\figh{5cm}

\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\begin{figure}[hb]
  \centering
  \input{testfig}
  \caption{Quite normal}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of the rendered LaTeX code with histogram]

Comment: `matplotlib` has a [pgf backend](http://matplotlib.org/users/pgf.html), if you just want pgf and don't require `pgfplots`.

Comment: @G.Poore Thanks, I'd forgotten about that. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Octave](http://www.octave.org). It has the [`print`](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Printing-and-Saving-Plots.html) command with the `-dtikz` option which exports a plot to PGF/TikZ code.

More precisely, because Octave includes two graphics toolkits:

- When the Gnuplot toolkit is active, this saves TikZ code.
- When FLTK is active, this saves lower-level PGF code.

Also it requires some configuration, because the exported code does not work instantly. The `pgfpicture` environment has to be changed to `tikzpicture`, and the TikZ code invokes gnuplot which requires including a package from the Octave supplied texmf tree, and passing the --enable-write18 option to (pdf)latex.

Comment: And when I got everything working, I decided that I'd rather export my matrices to plain text and use PGFPlots' `\addplot table` because that's more native and looks better when zoomed in on :)